# Using SearchManager's SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1 to display a local file

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I'm implementing my own `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider` and everything's working except one thing: I can't get the device search to display icons for the results. I'd like to display images from my application's data folder (located at `/{sdcard}/Android/data/package_name/files/`)

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1), it's achievable by using `SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1`, and it apparently supports a number of schemes, including `ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE`, which is `file`. Here's a quote from the official docs:

> Column name for suggestions cursor. *Optional.* If your cursor includes this column, then all suggestions will be provided in a format that includes space for two small icons, one at the left and one at the right of each suggestion. The data in the column must be a resource ID of a drawable, or a URI in one of the following formats:
>
> content (`SCHEME_CONTENT`)
>
> android.resource (`SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE`)
>
> file (`SCHEME_FILE`)

I've tried a number of obvious things, including manual creation of the file URI and automated creation using `Uri.Builder()`. None of this worked.

I also found someone else asking about the same thing on Google Groups, and it's sadly unanswered: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/MJj7GIaONjc

Does anyone have any experience in getting the device search to display local images from the device?

**UPDATE (December 15):**
I've just tried using the `ContentProvider` with a `SearchView` as the searchable info, and it works exactly as expected - including the cover art images. Still, global search doesn't show it...

Comment: What file URI structure have you tried?

Comment: I've tried "file://{file_path}", "file:/{file_path}" as well as {file_path}.

Comment: I wonder if perhaps you'll have to implement your own `ContentProvider` to expose the images in your app's `data` folder. Have you tried that? Could be worth a shot, especially since it's not too complicated. Alternatively, have you tried loading an image through the `file://` scheme from a more public location? For example, the root of the SD card?

Comment: I'd love to try, but I've just updated all my devices to Android 4.4 and for some reason that means I can no longer search the content of installed applications. Everything that worked before, including Google Play, no longer appear in the "Tablet search" / "Phone search" part of Google search. Strange...

Comment: Just created a question about that particular issue as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001979/global-search-not-working-as-expected-in-android-4-4

Comment: I just tried using `file://` and `file:/` for a public file (screenshot folder), and that still didn't work. Might have to create a `ContentProvider` for it to work - it's just weird when the documentation says it should work.

Comment: The following works for me: `"'" + uri + "' AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1` where `uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/path/to/file"))`. Note that `uri` needs to be within single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out as soon as I can. Can't get global search to work on Android 4.4, so I'll need to use a friend's phone.

Comment: @user2558882 Just tried it and I still can't get it to work. Can you perhaps add the solution as an answer with slightly more code?

Comment: Sure. Do you see an exception (a silent one perhaps)? Or, it just doesn't work?

Comment: Didn't notice any exceptions, but admittedly I wasn't looking for any in the Logcat output. It simply displays the app icon where it was supposed to display the images.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and could not make the other solutions work. I finally substituted the cursor with a new one containing the data I needed in query().

```
public class RecentQueriesProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {
    public final static String AUTHORITY = "com.package.RecentQueriesProvider";
    public final static int MODE = DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES;

    public RecentQueriesProvider() {
        setupSuggestions(AUTHORITY, MODE);
    }

    // We override query() to replace the history icon in the recent searches suggestions. We create a new cursor
    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Cursor superCursor = super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        Uri iconUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/drawable/ic_action_time");
        MatrixCursor newCursor = new MatrixCursor(superCursor.getColumnNames());
        superCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (superCursor.moveToNext()){
            newCursor.addRow(new Object[]{
                    superCursor.getInt(superCursor.getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_FORMAT)),
                    iconUri,
                    superCursor.getString(superCursor.getColumnIndex(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1)),
                    superCursor.getString(superCursor.getColumnIndex("suggest_intent_query")),
                    superCursor.getInt(superCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))
            });
        }
       return newCursor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to copy source code from `android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`, place it in your class that extends ContentProvider, and customize `setupSuggestions(String, int)`. Specifically, you would be changing this:

```
Uri uriFile = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/file"));

mSuggestionProjection = new String [] {
        "0 AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_FORMAT,

        // Here, you would return a file uri: 'uriFile'
        "'android.resource://system/"
                + com.android.internal.R.drawable.ic_menu_recent_history + "' AS "
                        + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1,
        "display1 AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
        "query AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY,
        "_id"
};
```

I prefer the following though. Extend `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider` and override the `query(...)` method. Here, intercept `SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY` and return a cursor.

```
public class SearchSuggestionProvider extends SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider {

    private UriMatcher matcher;

    private static final int URI_MATCH_SUGGEST = 1;

    public SearchSuggestionProvider() {
        super();

        matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

        // Add uri to return URI_MATCH_SUGGEST
        matcher.addURI(SearchSuggestionProvider.class.getName(), 
                         SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, URI_MATCH_SUGGEST);

        setupSuggestions(SearchSuggestionProvider.class.getName(), 
                                                           DATABASE_MODE_QUERIES);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, 
                                      String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        // special case for actual suggestions (from search manager)
        if (matcher.match(uri) == URI_MATCH_SUGGEST) {

            // File to use
            File f = new File("/path/to/file");

            Uri uriFile = Uri.fromFile(f);

            final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                "_id", 
                "display1 AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,                
                "query AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_QUERY,
                "'" + uriFile + "'" + " AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1,
            };

            final Uri URI = Uri.parse("content://" + 
                        SearchSuggestionProvider.class.getName() + "/suggestions");

            // return cursor
            return getContext().getContentResolver().query(
                URI, 
                PROJECTION, 
                "display1 LIKE ?", 
                new String[] {selectionArgs[0] + "%"}, 
                "date DESC");          
        }

        // Let super method handle the query if the check fails
        return super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I might have been a bit vague in my original question. If that's the case, I'm sorry. Here's a screenshot of what I've currently achieved: http://mizuu.tv/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/miz_global_search.jpg

Comment: The results come from a SQLite database that I query in the overridden `query(...)` method. I'd like each result to have a cover image shown alongside it. This solution seems to be useful for showing just one image, if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: @MichellBak First of all, the app looks awesome, nice work! I (kind of) understand what you are trying to do. And I'll be honest, I don't think I know the answer to this. What _might_ work: add another column to your table to store the image `Uri`. Add another item to the `PROJECTION` array: `"iconuri AS " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_ICON_1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try when possible. It doesn't seem like there are any other suggestions from people - apart from creating a contentprovider and see if that works - so I'll award you with the bounty, since it's about to expire, and leave the question unanswered for now.

Comment: @MichellBak No, thank you for the bounty, even though I wasn't much help. I'll give this a go again coming weekend and post back if I do find a way.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! :-) It's an annoying issue, especially when you can't test it yourself because all your devices run 4.4 :-(