# Indexing app locally and displaying results in Google Search

Tags: android, android-app-indexing

I was reading about indexing API presented on Google IO 2014 (developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/appindexingapi). One feature I am missing there (or couldn't find it) is local app indexing.

I will use example: I want to search my local content specific for me. I create an app where every user has different data. Just like notes from Google Keep or Evernote. I would like to expose data to google search just for that phone.

Am I right that it is not possible in current stage? Any ideas if Google will do it in the future?

Regards, Konrad

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be accomplished by implementing a [search interface](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) and setting includeInGlobalSearch flag in searchable.xml. But in 4.4 this option was [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21627271/341998).

Comment: That is exactly the answer I found as well. While everyone keeps referring to using app-indexing, I haven't yet found an authoritative answer as to how this can be done using app-indexing.